# How much lemons are needed to produce pure 1 kg lemon essential oil?

Tags: oil, lemon

First of, sorry of the question is not for here, but I can't seemk to find more proper place...
My question is, how much lemons are needed to produce 1 kilogram pure essential oil, not the method with olive oil, but pure one, with only lemons?

Comment: Might sound silly but it really depends on each lemon size and can't be predicted.

Comment: @ShadowWizard it surely depends, but I think that even giving an interval is interesting here. Or an average value, even if it is known that it will vary a lot. Assuming lemons 5 cm in the equatorial diameter, do I need 50 kilos or 500 on average?

Comment: an answer in kilograms is also accepted

Comment: The problem with an answer in kilograms is that it still depends on the lemon size. You only use the peel for making essential oils, and small lemons a higher peel-to-lemon ratio by weight than large lemons. And even an answer in kilograms of peel will have a variation, because the "juiciness" of peel will differ between cultivars, climate conditions during growth, ripeness and so on. But I must say that the range between the two existing answers is much larger than I expected, 3000 lemons vs 3500 lbs of rind is strange.

Comment: I have fixed my coversion error - it's closer to 3300 than 3500... Still a large discrepancy, though.

Comment: And I REALLY messed up the units. Note to self: multiplying # of lemons by a dimensionless conversion factor does not change a cardinal number into mass...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't personally tried making lemon essential oil. But according to Young Living, an MD named Jean Valnet estimated that it takes 3,000 lemons to produce one kilo of Lemon essential oil. Here are some links to the estimations (keep in mind that a kilogram is roughly 2.2 lbs):

- [Young Living](https://blog.youngliving.com/how-to-use-lemon-essential-oil/#.UwDwW_ldV8E) (states 3000 makes 1 kilo)
- [LemonMania](http://lemonmania.com/lemon-oil) (states 3000 makes 1 kilo)
- [Veriditas Botanicals](http://veriditasbotanicals.com/how-to-use-our-essential-oils-therapeutically/lemon/) (states 3000
  makes 2 lbs (about .91 kilo))

Comment: That blog says he *estimated* that - probably not a very high confidence number.

Comment: The problem is, given that lemons vary in size, I think the best one can get is an estimate.

Comment: I never said you could get an exact number, but estimates are not all of equal quality. The phrasing on the blog makes it sound like the guy has never actually made the oil, making it a lot less confident of a number than an estimate from someone who has.

Comment: Fair enough; I added more links with similar estimations if it helps any. I think they all fall in line with the answer above, so I would say between 3000 - 3300 lemons is a fair number for around a kilogram of oil.

Comment: What is a "2.2 lbs", I have traveled to four continents and never seen that :-)

Comment: @TFD "2.2 lbs" is an abbreviation for "2.2 pounds". I am a bit surprised to see that you don't know it after your travelling to four continents, since all the countries I've visited use the metric system and still it's somehow a standard abbreviation for me :)

Comment: @rumtscho it was a smilely. In imperial it's 2lb 3 oz = 1 Kg, or maybe 2 1/5 lb, but not 2.2 :-)

Comment: @TFD interesting. It must be a side effect of metric minds using an imperial unit now and then. I've encountered decimal places in lbs frequently enough that I didn't notice anything unusual. Now that you mention it, I've experienced it the other way around, an American describing to me a thickness as 1 3/8 cm. I was quite taken aback and had to do a lot of calculation in my head :)

Comment: @rumtscho AP is from USA :-) Must be the new generation that learnt metric in school, and then faced the harsh reality in the old world

Comment: 3000 Meyer lemons is about 30 bushels. You can grow about 30 bushels per square chain. So one acre should give you 20 lbs of oil :-)

Comment: @TFD The strange measurement is really just my ignorance. That source had listed the amount in lbs and I was trying to convert it to kilos for comparison, since all the other measurements were in kilos. I probably used an online conversion, which resulted in "2.2". Sorry for the confusion. I can edit if you like. :)

Comment: Also, at the risk of adding extraneous comments to this conversation, I haven't used the site a great deal and didn't realize that adding another measurement conversion for clarity would bump the question back up in the feed. I apologize for resurrecting an ancient question.

Comment: @Trillian No need to apologise, interesting question, and good answer. That's what this site is about. Thinking about planting some more lemon trees now :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how definitive this is, but it states that the rinds of 1500 lemons are required to make one pound of lemon essential oil http://www.everygreenherb.com/lemon.html

For a kilogram, you would need the rinds of around to 3300 lemons.

Comment: Measuring by rind weight sounds a lot more accurate than by lemon weight or number, too.

Comment: Don't you mean: the peels/rinds of 3300 lemons?

Comment: LOL yes, and I was just about to fix that. This may well remove the upvote, but deservedly so...

Comment: Dunno about removing it, but it means I can add mine :)